# onRemoveClicked() not displaying Correct Item Removal Price in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

So I have a BookStore Swing application in which I have the correct price display in the Method on addClicked()

```
//ACTION LISTENERS
/*
 * AddButtonListener - adds selected item to shopping cart upon selection
 */
private void onAddClicked(){
            selectedIndex = booksList.getSelectedIndex();
        selectedBookName = booksList.getSelectedValue();

        books = booksList.getModel();
        shoppingCart = selectedList.getModel();

        shoppingCartDFM = new DefaultListModel();

        for(count=0; count<shoppingCart.getSize(); count++){
            shoppingCartDFM.addElement(shoppingCart.getElementAt(count));
        }

    switch (selectedButton) {
        case FICTION:
            bookPrice += bookPrices[0];
            break;
        case NON_FICTION:
            bookPrice += bookPrices[bookPrices.length-1];
            break;
        default:
            bookPrice += bookPrices[selectedIndex];
            break;
    }

        shoppingCartDFM.addElement(selectedBookName);
        selectedList.setModel(shoppingCartDFM);
}
```

The method on Removal Click will display the wrong price when fiction and non fiction books are mixed together and then removed individually. The final checkout will always be over 0 when no books exist in the cart.

```
    /*
 * RemoveButtonListener - Removes selected item from shopping cart upon selection
 */

private void onRemoveClicked(){
            index = selectedList.getSelectedIndex();
                    if(index>=0){
        ((DefaultListModel)selectedList.getModel()).remove(index);


                            switch (selectedButton) {
        case FICTION:
            bookPrice -= bookPrices[0];
            break;
        case NON_FICTION:
            bookPrice -= bookPrices[bookPrices.length-1];
            break;
        default:
            bookPrice -= bookPrices[selectedIndex];
            break;
    }
}
}
```

All Global variables here

```
 private static final int ALL=1;
private static final int FICTION=2;
private static final int NON_FICTION=3;

private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH= 800;     //Width of GUI frame
private static final int WINDOW_LENGTH = 250;   //Length of GUI frame

private JPanel booksPanel;          //Holds all the books
private JPanel buttonsPanel;        //Has add/remove/checkout buttons
private JPanel shoppingCartPanel;   //To hold books added by user
private JPanel bannerPanel;         //Banner panel
private JPanel fictionButtonsPanel; //Holds search/showall buttons

private JList booksList;            //List with all book names
private JList selectedList;         //List in shopping cart

private JButton addSelected;        //Adds book to shopping cart
private JButton removeSelected;     //Removes book from shopping cart
private JButton checkOut;           //Adds all books prices + taxes
private JButton fictionButton;      //Searches for desired book
private JButton showAllButton;      //shows all books available
private JButton nonFictionButton;       //Searches for Non Fiction Books


private BookList bookList; 
private String[] bookNames;
private String[] fictionBooksNames;
private String[] nonFictionBookNames;

    private int selectedButton=ALL;

private double[] bookPrices;//Array that holds all book prices



private JScrollPane scrollPane1;    //Holds available books list
private JScrollPane scrollPane2;    //Holds selected book list

private JLabel panelTitle;          //Panel title
private JLabel cartTitle;           //Panel title
private JLabel banner;              //Panel title

private int element = -1;           // control variable
private int selectedIndex;          //Index selected among available books
private int index;                  //Int that holds selected index.
private int i,count;                //Control variables

private double total;               //Total of prices
private double bookPrice;           //Hold book prices
private final double TAX=0.06;      //Constant for tax value

private ListModel books;            //List model for book name list
private ListModel shoppingCart;     //List model for shopping cart list
private DefaultListModel shoppingCartDFM;

private DecimalFormat money;        //Money format
private Object selectedBookName;    //Selected book

private String searchResults;       //Hold search results
private String notFound = " Title not found";   //Holds search results

private boolean found = false;
```

Does anyone see the logic flaw that makes removing books produce the incorrect price when mixing fiction and non fiction?

Comment: I think you should post an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), ie a fully runnable standalone (and small) program for us to test, which reproduces the error.

Comment: @gthanop Great suggestion, and a tip: `[mre]` in a comment auto expends to [mre].